# For f, g, h, all with domain N+ and range a subset of R+, proove that if f is Θ(h) and g is Θ(h) then f/g is Θ(1),

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The answer states that from the hypothesis there exists a constant *c<sub>1</sub>* such that *f(n) ≤ c<sub>1</sub>h(n)* and a constant *c<sub>2</sub>* such that *g(n) ≥ c<sub>2</sub>h(n)*, but I don't understand how they are different in the signs? Aren't they both Θ(h)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Being Θ(h) means than a function is both bound from above and below, i.e. it is both O(h) and Ω(h). Because f(n) is Θ(h) it is O(h) and so f(n) ≤ c_1 h(n) for some c_1 and sufficiently large n. Because g is Θ(h) then g is Ω(h) and so g(n) ≥ c_2 h(n) for some c_2 and sufficiently large n.